# From a sentence count distinct words per line in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, nlp, nltk

I am analogizing data where I have sentences one in each row example

```
PhraseCleaned   
0   get house business distribute sell outside house opportunities  
1   business changing offices culture work business
2   search company best practices 
3   1 let go back desk spaces one
```

This are all sentences I need to count the words per line how many times same words and get something like this

```
id    PhraseCleaned 
0   get house business house opportunities  
1   business changing offices culture work business
2   desk big work culture
```

This image is what I really need to get to

[image: image of what I want to get]

I did this

```
tokenaize_data= PraseFinalD.apply(lambda row: nltk.word_tokenize(row['PhraseCleaned']), axis=1)
```

and it will separate the words per commas

```
[get, house, business, house, opportunities ]
[business, changing, offices, culture, work, business]
[desk, big, work, culture]
```

Now I am trying to count them this is just counting all words together PhaseFinal is a list.. that I cleaned up the data removing some things

```
word2count = {} 
for data in PhraseFinal: 
words = nltk.word_tokenize(data) 
for word in words: 
    if word not in word2count.keys(): 
        word2count[word] = 1
    else: 
        word2count[word] += 1
```

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: **_This image is what I really need to get to_** is not really a good strategy.  What is the point for that format?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The point I want to get is so I can plot later the words per category that I have per answer..  I am not able to get to that result if I run that look it will just count the words no per line it will count distinct them all the lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Given your data as `df`
2. Create a dict of word counts with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and split it into columns with `.tolist()`
3. Join it to `df`

```py
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

# create a word count dict and split it into columns
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['PhraseCleaned'].apply(lambda x: Counter(x.split())).tolist())

print(df1)

 get  house  business  distribute  sell  outside  opportunities  changing  offices  culture  work  search  company  best  practices    1  let   go  back  desk  spaces  one
 1.0    2.0       1.0         1.0   1.0      1.0            1.0       NaN      NaN      NaN   NaN     NaN      NaN   NaN        NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN  NaN
 NaN    NaN       2.0         NaN   NaN      NaN            NaN       1.0      1.0      1.0   1.0     NaN      NaN   NaN        NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN  NaN
 NaN    NaN       NaN         NaN   NaN      NaN            NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN   NaN     1.0      1.0   1.0        1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN  NaN
 NaN    NaN       NaN         NaN   NaN      NaN            NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN   NaN     NaN      NaN   NaN        NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0   1.0   1.0     1.0  1.0

# join df and df1
df2 = df.join(df1)

print(df2)

                                                  PhraseCleaned  get  house  business  distribute  sell  outside  opportunities  changing  offices  culture  work  search  company  best  practices    1  let   go  back  desk  spaces  one
 get house business distribute sell outside house opportunities  1.0    2.0       1.0         1.0   1.0      1.0            1.0       NaN      NaN      NaN   NaN     NaN      NaN   NaN        NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN  NaN
                business changing offices culture work business  NaN    NaN       2.0         NaN   NaN      NaN            NaN       1.0      1.0      1.0   1.0     NaN      NaN   NaN        NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN  NaN
                                  search company best practices  NaN    NaN       NaN         NaN   NaN      NaN            NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN   NaN     1.0      1.0   1.0        1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN  NaN
                                  1 let go back desk spaces one  NaN    NaN       NaN         NaN   NaN      NaN            NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN   NaN     NaN      NaN   NaN        NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0   1.0   1.0     1.0  1.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is what I was looking for it is perfect I have never use collections.

Answer (score 0):

With `scikit-learn` vectorizer:

```
from operator import itemgetter

import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

df = pd.DataFrame({'text': texts})

# Initialize the counter.
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
# Get the unique vocabulary and get the counts.
vectorizer.fit_transform(df['text'])

# Using idiom from https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/basic-nlp-with-nltk/#To-vectorize-any-new-sentences,-we-use--CountVectorizer.transform()
# Print the words sorted by their index
words_sorted_by_index, _ = zip(*sorted(vectorizer.vocabulary_.items(), key=itemgetter(1)))
print('Vocab:', words_sorted_by_index)
print()
print('Matrix/Vectors:\n', vectorizer.transform(df['text']).toarray())
```

[out]:

```
Vocab: ('back', 'best', 'business', 'changing', 'company', 'culture', 'desk', 'distribute', 'get', 'go', 'house', 'let', 'offices', 'one', 'opportunities', 'outside', 'practices', 'search', 'sell', 'spaces', 'work')

Matrix/Vectors:
 [[0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 2 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 2 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]]
```

Putting it back to the DataFrame.

```
from operator import itemgetter

import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

texts = """get house business distribute sell outside house opportunities
business changing offices culture work business
search company best practices 
1 let go back desk spaces one""".split('\n')

df = pd.DataFrame({'text': texts})

# Initialize the counter.
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
# Get the unique vocabulary and get the counts.
vectorizer.fit_transform(df['text'])

# Using idiom from https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/basic-nlp-with-nltk/#To-vectorize-any-new-sentences,-we-use--CountVectorizer.transform()
# Print the words sorted by their index
words_sorted_by_index, _ = zip(*sorted(vectorizer.vocabulary_.items(), key=itemgetter(1)))
matrix = vectorizer.transform(df['text']).toarray()

# Putting it back to the DataFrame.
df_new = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(matrix)], axis=1)
column_names = dict(zip(range(len(words_sorted_by_index)), words_sorted_by_index))
df_new.rename(column_names, axis=1)
```

And to write it out to a 'csv' file:

```
df_new.to_csv('data-analogize.csv', index=False)
```